# bootstrap 4 validation disable submit button until form validated

Tags: javascript, validation, bootstrap-4, submit-button, disable

In the following example of my problem I have 2 fields needing to be validate.
Until all (2 in this case) fields are validated, the submit button should be disabled.
If both are validated it should be enabled.

**My problem:** The minute the first field is validated - the button is enabled, which is too early.
I understand (ot think that I do) that this occurs because of where I placed **`$("#submitBtn").attr("disabled",false);`**

Any hint of how to get it work would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** For an example of a full registration form with the submit button enabled ONLY when all the form's elements are validated, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766548/bootstrap-4-validation-with-password-confirmation-and-submit-disabled-until-form).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
  input[type="submit"]:disabled {
    background-color: red;      }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
        <form action="page2.php" id="myForm1" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-z]{3,6}$" required autofocus>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">a to z only (3 to 6 long)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-z]{3,6}$" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">a to z only (3 to 6 long)</div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" disabled>Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      let currForm1 = document.getElementById('myForm1');
      // Validate on input:
      currForm1.querySelectorAll('.form-control').forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener(('input'), () => {
          if (input.checkValidity()) {
            input.classList.remove('is-invalid')
            input.classList.add('is-valid');
            $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled",false);           <<<<======== ??????
          } else {
            input.classList.remove('is-valid')
            input.classList.add('is-invalid');
          }
        });
      });
      // Validate on submit:
      currForm1.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (currForm1.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        currForm1.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Inside `input.addEventListener[...]` add another validation. Check if all inputs have the `is-valid` class. If so, use `$("#submitBtn").attr("disabled",false);` there.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Thanks. That makes sense. Since I'm new to JS and BS, could you please save me the time and tell me the syntax for checking if all inputs have the `is-valid` class? I've been chasing my tail over it for hours now...

Comment: `var is_valid = $('.form-control').length === $('.form-control.is-valid').length`, so `if (is_valid) { [yourcodehere]...}`.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Thank you!!! That worked fine for me. If you put it as and answer - I will accept it. (I now see that there are already 2 answers which I'll check out now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your input event listener check if all the inputs have an `is-valid` class. If all your inputs have an `is-valid` class, turn off the disabled button.

```
currForm1.querySelectorAll('.form-control').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener(('input'), () => {
    if (input.checkValidity()) {
      input.classList.remove('is-invalid')
      input.classList.add('is-valid');
      // $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled",false);           <<<<======== ??????
    } else {
      input.classList.remove('is-valid')
      input.classList.add('is-invalid');
    }
    var is_valid = $('.form-control').length === $('.form-control.is-valid').length;
    $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", !is_valid);
  });
});
```

Comment: I've noticed that your solution is not 100% perfect : only after entering valid input in all fields the button is enabled.That's good! But if, before hitting the button, I go back to any of the fields and make it invalid (e.g. by deleting characters so it's below the required minimum - the button stays enabled. I think it's good enough for my project, but it would be so much more elegant if this small issue would be resolved too. Any idea...?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Wow! When I grow up I want to be JM-AGMS...  Thank you so much! It is a 100% solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is good approach or not and it also depend on your requirement if it fulfil your need so that's fine..

here i'm removing some line and adding some line

1. remove disable button code from first condition and added at the last

```js
if(input.checkValidity() && index ===1) {
    $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", false); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    input[type="submit"]:disabled {
      background-color: red;      }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
          <form action="page2.php" id="myForm1" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-z]{3,6}$" required autofocus>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Valid</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">a to z only (3 to 6 long)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" pattern="^[a-z]{3,6}$" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Valid</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">a to z only (3 to 6 long)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" disabled>Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        let currForm1 = document.getElementById('myForm1');
        // Validate on input:
        currForm1.querySelectorAll('.form-control').forEach((input, index) => {
          input.addEventListener(('input'), () => {
            if (input.checkValidity()) {
              console.log(input.checkValidity());
              input.classList.remove('is-invalid')
              input.classList.add('is-valid');      
            } else {
              input.classList.remove('is-valid')
              input.classList.add('is-invalid');
            }
            if(input.checkValidity() && index ===1) {
              $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", false); 
            }
          });
        });
        // Validate on submit:
        currForm1.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          if (currForm1.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
          currForm1.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I found @JM-AGMS's solution perfect for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

We need to check if all the other inputs are also valid before assuming that we can just enable it

```
let currForm1 = document.getElementById('myForm1');
      // Validate on input:
      currForm1.querySelectorAll('.form-control').forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener(('input'), () => {
          if (input.checkValidity()) {
            /* IF IT PASSES WE NEED TO CHECK THE OTHER INPUTS */

            /* STORE ALL THE INPUTS THAT PASS THE CHECKVALIDITY */
            let allValid = currForm1.querySelectorAll('.form-control').filter(input => 
              { return input.checkValidity() })

            /* WE CAN NOW UPDATE THE SUBMIT BASED ON THE NUMBER OF VALID 
               INPUTS WE HAVE */
            $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", allValid.length === currForm1.querySelectorAll('.form-control').length); 

            input.classList.remove('is-invalid')
            input.classList.add('is-valid');   
          } else {

            /* IF IT FAILS WE DONT NEED TO CHECK WE WANT THE VALIDATOR AS FALSE */
            $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", true); 
            input.classList.remove('is-valid')
            input.classList.add('is-invalid');
          }
        });
      });

      /* FINALLY WE CAN UPDATE THE SUBMIT, BASED ON OUR VARIABLE */
      $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", validatorForSubmit );
```

Comment: Thank you. I found @JM-AGMS's solution perfect for me. Thanks again.